# Error when trying with Azure Government endpoint with Azure Storage Java Library

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-gov

I am trying to use the Azure Storage Java library with the Azure Government endpoints. My code is as follows.

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
```

`connectionString` has the suffix of Azure Gov cloud. For some reason the values for the blob.storage URI are still marked as `blob.core.windows.net` and I receive the following error. I am unable to run any blob operations.

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The server encountered an unknown failure: at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:178)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:214)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer.exists(CloudBlobContainer.java:749)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer.exists(CloudBlobContainer.java:736)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer.exists(CloudBlobContainer.java:710)
at com.scalegrid.cloudconnector.azure.AzureStorageClient.createContainerIfItDoesntExist(AzureStorageClient.java:369)

java.net.UnknownHostException: XXXX.core.usgovcloudapi.net
ERROR ~ s failed.
Code:12207
```

Is there any way I can get this to work ?

**Update**

I was using an earlier version of the Azure storage Java. Storage endpoints have not been added at this point. Updating to the newer version fixed it.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the connection string you're using? Please replace account name/key with random values before sharing.

Comment: Any progress now?

Comment: yes, I forgot updating this ticket. I was using an earlier version of the Azure storage SDK and they did not add the gov cloud endpoints at that time. updating it to the newer version fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The only modification you need from the Code Sample in the [azure-storage-java README.md](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) is to **add `EndpointSuffix` in your connection string for the Azure Government endpoints**.

Here's the modified sample Java code:

```java
import java.io.*;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*;

public class BlobSample {
    public static final String storageConnectionString =
        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;"
        + "AccountName=your_account_name;"
        + "AccountKey=your_account_key"
        + "EndpointSuffix=core.usgovcloudapi.net";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient serviceClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();

            // Container name must be lower case.
            CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.getContainerReference("myimages");
            container.createIfNotExists();

            // Upload an image file.
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("image1.jpg");
            File sourceFile = new File("c:\\myimages\\image1.jpg");
            blob.upload(new FileInputStream(sourceFile), sourceFile.length());

            // Download the image file.
            File destinationFile = new File(sourceFile.getParentFile(), "image1Download.tmp");
            blob.downloadToFile(destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.out.print("FileNotFoundException encountered: ");
            System.out.println(fileNotFoundException.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        catch (StorageException storageException) {
            System.out.print("StorageException encountered: ");
            System.out.println(storageException.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Exception encountered: ");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the snippet of C# code from [official page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-get-started-connect-to-storage).

```
var credentials = new StorageCredentials(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);

var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, "core.usgovcloudapi.net", useHttps: true);
```

So , I think you need to change the way you initialize the client.

I found the above method in the [Java official sdk](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/).

```
CloudStorageAccount(StorageCredentials storageCredentials, boolean useHttps, String endpointSuffix)
Creates an instance of the CloudStorageAccount class using the specified account credentials.
```

So , please refer to the sample code below to modify your code.

```
 StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey storageCredentials =  new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(<your account name>, <your account key>);

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount  = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true, "core.windows.net");

// Create the Azure Files client.
 CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();
```

Please note that you can find your own gov `Endpointsuffix` parameters  at the end of the connectstring on portal.

Hope it helps you.